# Racism, sexism, ageism... any term for degree-based prejudice?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word to designate prejudice against someone based on the degrees he holds or the university he attends/attended?

Comment: Perhaps "elitism"?

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed quite close. Ideally I'd like something a bit more specific to degrees.

Comment: Brain *dis*Trust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Credentialism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credentialism_and_educational_inflation) seems to fit.

> undue emphasis on credentials (as college degrees) as prerequisites
>   to employment

[Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credentialism)

This definition suggests that the word is most commonly used about employment discrimination specifically, and that agrees with my own intuition (although I don't think it's absolutely limited to this context – it might also be used when talking about the perceived credibility of authorities).

In the context of social discrimination or general negative attitudes towards people with less education, I think Hot Lick's suggestion of **elitism** might work better.